# Laravel 5.2 Class 'App\authors' not found

Tags: laravel, frameworks

Error is:

> FatalErrorException in AuthorsController.php line 28: Class
>   'App\authors' not found

Line 28:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\authors;

use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AuthorsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show()
    {
        $authors = authors::all();  LINE 28
        return view('authors', ['authors'=> $authors]);
    }
}
```

**Authors class:**

```
<?php

namespace App;
use App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class authors extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'authors';
}
```

I don t get it where the mistake is... I am new to Laravel.

Comment: Show the `authors` class please.

Comment: It is Laravel 5.2

Comment: Case sensitivity can matter. Is your class in `app/authors.php` or `app/Authors.php`?

Comment: It is author.php.

Comment: Lol, here was the mistake. I had author.php, not authors.php. Please post your answer to select it as good one. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try App\Author;

Check your spelling errors. Hope you get fixed